# How do I provide only the year in a citation in R markdown?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, bibliography

My rmarkdown script looks as follows:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "me"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%d %B, %Y")`'
output:
  pdf_document: default
  bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

In his book Helsel explains how to approach censored environmental data [@helsel_statistics_2012].
```

MY .bib file as such:

```
@book{helsel_statistics_2012,
    address = {Hoboken, N.J},
    edition = {2nd ed},
    series = {Wiley series in statistics in practice},
    title = {Statistics for censored environmental data using {Minitab} and {R}},
    isbn = {978-0-470-47988-9},
    publisher = {Wiley},
    author = {Helsel, Dennis R.},
    year = {2012},
    note = {00003 OCLC: ocn748290711},
    keywords = {Environmental sciences, Measurement Statistical methods, Minitab, Pollution, R (Computer program language), Statistical methods},
}
```

**When I knit the file I get the following output:**

In his book Helsel explains how to approach censored environmental data (Helsel 2012).

**Question: How can I return the year only in the in citation (as I already state the author in the text)?**

In his book Helsel **(2012)** explains how to approach censored environmental data.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the rmarkdown (.Rmd) file put the following (note the removal of [ ] brackets from [@helsel_statistics_2012]):

```
In his book @helsel_statistics_2012 explains how to approach censored environmental data.
```

Once rendered this will give you the desired output:

```
In his book Helsel (2012) explains how to approach censored environmental data.
```

If you really only want the year from the citation then:

```
[-@helsel_statistics_2012]
```

returns:

```
(2012)
```

For more details see the rmarkdown documetation on citations  http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html